# Safari 7.1 breaking outline-color and overflow?

Tags: css, safari

I've upgraded to Safari 7.1, and it seems to have broken a couple of css lines. They worked with Safari 7.0.x and continue to work in other browsers, like Chrome.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and

```
outline-color: [color];
```

Specifically, I am using "overflow:hidden;" to stop the background from scrolling when moused over a scrolling div:

```
$("ul.selectList, ul.comboBoxList, ul.multiSelectList").mouseenter(function(){$("body").css("overflow","hidden")});
$("ul.selectList, ul.comboBoxList, ul.multiSelectList").mouseleave(function(){$("body").css("overflow","initial")});
```

...and I'm using outline-color to change the color of a text input's outline when focused:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea { outline-color: $medium-green; outline-width: 5px; }
```

Is anybody else running into these problems?

---

### Update: Looks like the overflow problem fixed itself, but the outline-color problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

try `outline: $medium-green solid 5px !important;` instead